# Calculating Age from Date of Birth with where condition on Age in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

How to calculate age with where condition on age again ? I want all users only of age < 50 year

My query is working fine without where condition but when i am adding `WHERE age < 50` it's give me an error `#1054 - Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'`

```
SELECT u.*, YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(u.user_dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < 
RIGHT(u.user_dob, 5)) as age FROM tbl_users as u WHERE age < 50
```

Comment: Cannot use alias in where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something simpler like this?

```
where dob >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 50 year)
```

If you want the age, you can take the difference in years:

```
select timestampdiff(year, dob, curdate())
```

Comment: yes you are right where dob >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 50 year) is best and simpler

Answer (score 2):

update your age in where clause with this:

```
YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(u.user_dob) - (
RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) <
RIGHT(u.user_dob, 5))
```

to be:

```
SELECT u.*, YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(u.user_dob) - (
RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) <
RIGHT(u.user_dob, 5)) AS age
FROM tbl_users AS u
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(u.user_dob) - (
RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) <
RIGHT(u.user_dob, 5)) < 50
```